Cauchy conditions and continuity of $f(z)$
Let $f(z) = f(r,\theta) = \sqrt{r}(\cos(\theta/2) + i \sin(\theta/2)) = P(r,\theta) + iQ(r,\theta)$ be a function defined on
$$
\Omega = \left\lbrace z\in \mathbb{C}| \mathbb{R} \ni r > 0, \theta \in ]0,\pi[ \right\rbrace. 
$$
By using the Cauchy conditions in polar coordinates, it is immediate to show that $f(z)$ is an holomorphic function.
If now we consider the same function on
$$
\bar{\Omega} = \left\lbrace z\in \mathbb{C}| \mathbb{R} \ni r > 0, \theta \in [0,\pi] \right\rbrace, 
$$
that is the half positive plane including the real axis, what can be said about $f(z)$ ?
I'm trying to well understand the use of the Cauchy conditions in this kind of "situations" (as for the logarithmic function...)

Your function $f$ is a square root function on the open upper half plane $\mathbb H$. In fact, $f(z)^2 = z$ for $z \in \mathbb  H$.
You correctly extend it the closed upper half plane minus the origin, but it does not make sense to call this extension holomorphic because its domain is not an open subset of $\mathbb C$. However, you can extend $f$ to the even bigger set
$$\Omega' = \left \{ z \in \mathbb C\mid r > 0, \theta \in \left] - \frac \pi 2, \frac{3\pi}{2} \right[ \right \}$$
This set is open in $\mathbb C$ and you easily check that the extension of $f$ is holomorphic.
